# Newbie WPF question regarding style sharing

Tags: wpf

I have a assembly(dll) that is defining a number of user controls 
in one of the user controls I have some XAML like so

```
<UserControl>
<UserControl.Resources>
<Style x:Key="roundTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None" />
     .
     .
     .
     .

    </Style>
   <grid>...</grid>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

how can I reshare this style across all my user control xaml files
thanks

Answer (score 2):

put it in Application.Resources instead of UserControl.Resources